# SQL Server docker cannot be accessed in .NET Application

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core

I have a .NET Core application that runs with SQL Server. When I ran my application with the connection string of `server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;database=Innovent;Trusted_Connection=true;` which I took from The Microsoft Documentation, it is working great.

However, When I tried to run the SQL Server through docker, I received this error
`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.`.

And this is the connection string `Server={server},{port};Initial Catalog={database};User ID ={user};Password={password};Trusted_Connection=true;`. where server is `localhost`, port is `1433` and my dbname is `Innovent` user is the SA.

As I ran the docker container, I can access the server remotely as shown in the image below from Microsoft SQLServer Management Studio

[image]

Could anyone please help me know on what I did wrong?

Please let me know if you need any more info

Comment: where you run sql-server docker, on wsl2 ?

Comment: @arief21 I ran my sql-server on windows atm. But I am planning to release it on linux

Comment: What's the real value of `{server}` inside your connection string? Localhost, network machine name or what?

Comment: @AndrewSilver the value is localhost. I have figured it out. the server should be my machine IP Address instead of localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"localhost" doesn't work inside of docker container, because docker network  is a separate network and "localhost" is just a reserved name for "this PC".
Try to use "host.docker.internal", such record is being added into the "hosts" file by "Docker for windows" installer.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Trusted_Connection=true; from the connection string and rebuild the container.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35571369)

Comment: Since it is Docker, Trusted_Connection will probably not works, so try removing it from the connection string and adding username/password to it.